# Eclipse not displaying errors with Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I relatively new to using Eclipse with the Android SDK. Whenever I encounter an error/force close, Eclipse displays a page showing "Source not found"

Is it possible to get it to show the error that is causing this? I assume this is achieved by somehow linking to the android source code. Is this mistaken?

Basically, I am struggling to identify the source of my error, and am hoping eclipse can offer more information than at present.

Appreciate any help with this,
Venatu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source not found because the Exception is raised from something that you don't have source code, (e.g. Android SDK). You should always refer to the LogCat (Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> LogCat) to get the extended information about your exceptions.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Comment: Thanks for the help that was exactly what I was looking for! Chosen as answer for the link

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most likely eclipse tries to access the android code, which isnt possible since its a library. If you get a force close or any other crash it's always a good idea to take a look inside the logcat, Android prints the stacktrace there. You can usually see exactly which function and codeline causes the issue.

Open the logcat either inside Eclipse via Window->Show View->Other->Log cat 
or by starting the ddms application inside the android-sdk/tools directory.